# create resources using given template file using CDK with pipeline automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, pipeline, aws-cdk

[![codecommit containing cloudformation template][1]][1]I have a requirement where I need to create pipeline which is responsible for taking template yaml file as an input and create resources accordingly.

The approach which I took is providing the path of template yaml file in codebuild stage with command as:
"aws cloudformation deploy --template-file D:/pipeline/aws-waf.yml --stack-name waf-deployment"

````js
export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
  constructor(app: App, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps) {
    super(app, id, props);

    const code = codecommit.Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, 'ImportedRepo',
      props.repoName);

    const cdkBuild = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'CdkBuild', {
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: '0.2',
        phases: {
          install: {
            commands: 'npm install',
          },
          build: {
            commands: [
              'npm run build',
              'npm run cdk synth -- -o dist',
              'aws cloudformation deploy --template-file D:/pipeline/aws-waf.yml --stack-name waf-deployment',
              'echo $?'
            ],
          },
        },
        artifacts: {
          'base-directory': 'dist',
          files: [
            'LambdaStack.template.json',
          ],
        },
      }),
      environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_3,
      },
    });

    const sourceOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact();
    const cdkBuildOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact('CdkBuildOutput');
    //const lambdaBuildOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact('LambdaBuildOutput');
    new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      stages: [
        {
          stageName: 'Source',
          actions: [
            new codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction({
              actionName: 'CodeCommit_Source',
              repository: code,
              output: sourceOutput,
            }),
          ],
        },
        {
          stageName: 'Build',
          actions: [
              new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
              actionName: 'CDK_Build',
              project: cdkBuild,
              input: sourceOutput,
              outputs: [cdkBuildOutput],
            }),
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7rRe.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzk6v.png
````

Answer (score 2):

Im not fully sure of exactly what you are looking for so maybe consider updating your question to be more specific. However, I took the question as you are looking for the correct way to deploy cloud formation/cdk given a file in a codepipeline?

The way that we handle deployments of cloudformation via codepipeline is by leverage codebuild and codedeploy. The pipeline sources the file / change from a repository (optional, could use many other triggers), codebuild then uploads the file to s3 using the aws cli, once that file has been uploaded to s3 you can use codedeploy to deploy cloudformation from a source file in s3.

So for your example above, I would update the build to upload the new artifact to s3, and then create a new step in your pipeline to use codedeploy to deploy that s3 template.

Its entirely possible to build a script/codebuild commands to do the cloudformation deploy as well but because codedeploy already supports tracking that change, error handling etc I would recommend using a codedeploy for cloudformation deploys.

Note:
if you are not using an existing cloudformation template (json/yaml) and instead using cdk you will need synthesize your cdk into a cloudformation template before uploading to s3.

Comment: thanks @Corey Smith.. I do have cloudformation template (yaml) but not sure how to provide path of it to upload to s3 and then make codedeploy to point to s3 and deploy it in codedeploy phase.. everytinme it is giving me error as invalid path..

Comment: To be more specific I have a file in codecommit repo similar to [link] (https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/aws-waf-security-automations/v2.3.3/aws-waf-security-automations.template) .. I wan to deploy this cloudformation in either stage codebuild or codedeploy... I hope this makes sense..

Comment: Yes, then I would look into using a codebuild to upload the file to s3 using the aws cli in your codebuild. Something like `aws s3 cp ./cfn.yaml s3://example-bucket/dir/file`. Then after codebuild have another step of codedeploy to deploy that file to cloudformation (this is a configurable option in codedeploy).  @ManoharKumarSingh

Comment: Thanks for your help!! could you please suggest me any reference to this using CDK. current code for deploy :

stageName: 'Deploy',
          actions: [
            new codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
              actionName: 'WAF_CFN_Deploy',
              templatePath: cdkBuildOutput.atPath('PipelineDeployingLambdaStack.template.json'),
              stackName: 'WAFDeploymentStack',
              adminPermissions: true,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547003/how-to-deploy-a-cloudformation-stack-using-codepipeline-when-both-the-cfn-templ Provides examples of using codedeploy to deploy cloudformation in CDK. @ManoharKumarSingh